# Change subfolders from folder to another using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, directory, drive

Hope you're fine !

Previously, I coded a script that automatically creates subfolders into a "master folder". But, today, some of these subfolders concern the same topic so I had to create folders into the "master folder" to group them.

I Tried this but it doesn't work. I don't know if the function moveTo is able to folder.. because my argument is invalid

May someone can help me please ?

```
  function moveToMaster() {


// 1.0 : Parameters

const id = "(Insert Master Folder ID)"; // ID de FRANCE dans la technical Beebox || Mettre un lien d'exemple en attendant || ID France : 0B5Fxl24PGwR0NXFvU3NrQVBoZkk
const sp = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1WLtQkjkx6WY-3yMlAPTNSr-0kgGpCR69mC9fvLrgNz8'); // Ouvres le spreadsheet pour y récupérer des informations
const lumwork = sp.getSheetByName("Test"); // Ouvres la feuille "Extraction LumWork" du spreadsheet
const data = lumwork.getDataRange().getValues();
const master = sp.getSheetByName("Référentiel dossier maître").getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); 
  Logger.log(master)  

  for (var i = 1 ; i <= data.length-1 ; i++){
    var storeNbr = lumwork.getRange(i+1,2).getDisplayValue();
      Logger.log(storeNbr)
    var storeName = lumwork.getRange(i+1,3).getDisplayValue();
      Logger.log(storeName)
    var ID = lumwork.getRange(i+1,4).getDisplayValue();
      
      filteredData = master.filter(function(elem){
  return(elem[0] == storeNbr);
      })       
      Logger.log("Test : "+filteredData)


  var masterName = storeName+" "+storeNbr;  
  var folder = getOrMakeFolder(id,masterName); 
    Logger.log(folder);

      var folderId = DriveApp.getFolderById(ID);
      var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder)
      folderId.moveTo(destFolder);

  }
}
```

Comment: Your funciton should work provided `ID` and `folder` are valid folderIds / log them both to doublecheck.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. My two variables ID and folder return me the name of subfolders. When I tried to add "getId()", I have an exception issue : The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.Folder.moveTo.

Comment: Evidently  `destFolder` is a string not a folder.  Fix it. Make it a folder

Answer (score 1):

### You need to obtain the folder ids from the folder names

You can do it with:

```js
var id = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder)[0].getId();
```

whereby `folder` in this case needs to be the name of a folder.

Mind that Google Drive allows to have more than one file / folder with the same name, so the above solution will only work reliably if your folders have unique names.

See also: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfoldersbynamename